# Bluetooth emulator

Tags: 10.10, software-recommendation

I am looking for a piece of software which simulates a Bluetooth device in Ubuntu 10.10.

Because I have to test some Bluetooth applications, for example blueman.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

I can see the scope for this but I would argue that buying low-end hardware would just be cheaper if you put any value on your time at all.

You can buy a tiny USB bluetooth adapter for £1.26 including delivery and various bluetooth devices (I don't know what you want to test) from as little as £4.77 (eg a headset).

It's also a better representation of the real world. Emulated testing can often show problems that don't really exist or hide ones that do.

Comment: But is there really no way to emulate a bluetoothdevice?

Comment: +1. Bluetooth receivers are so cheap these days that it's not worth the effort to set up anything that emulates it - and having the uncertainty of whether the emulator is really accurate enough.

Comment: To emulate a bluetooth device you would need to develop a bluetooth driver getting it's input from a different source, this would be far more complex than buying a real device.